Connect akeneo PIM System to identity server
has anyone of you guys experience in connecting akeneo PIM system to identity server or keycloak. I am trying to find a way of having a single-sign-on approach so that the users does not have to login to akeneo if they are already logged in to their internal identity server instance.
Any hint or help would greatly appreciated :)

I believe you will only have this available on enterprise version out of the box.
You can install symfony bundles like https://github.com/mainick/KeycloakClientBundle and get it integrated.
